# How can I write and read JSON using sockets?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have been struggling with this for a while and I really have no idea how to solve the problem. I am using `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` to communicate with a Java server.

Writing to the server works fine, but whenever I call `reader.beginArray()`, I get an `EOFException`, so I have no idea how to both read from and write to the server correctly.
Error:

```
02-19 19:10:07.576: W/System.err(1334):     java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
02-19 19:10:07.586: W/System.err(1334):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:943)
02-19 19:10:07.606: W/System.err(1334):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextValue(JsonReader.java:771)
02-19 19:10:07.606: W/System.err(1334):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:367)
02-19 19:10:07.606: W/System.err(1334):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:337)
02-19 19:10:07.617: W/System.err(1334):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:306)
02-19 19:10:07.617: W/System.err(1334):     at com.example.lecture9.MyService.write(MyService.java:40)
02-19 19:10:07.617: W/System.err(1334):     at com.example.lecture9.MyService.connect(MyService.java:70)
02-19 19:10:07.626: W/System.err(1334):     at com.example.lecture9.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:84)
```

---

```
    @Override
        public void write(Message msg) throws IOException{
            //gson = new Gson();
            //writer = new JsonWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")));
            //reader = new JsonReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")));
            writer.beginArray();

            gson.toJson(msg, msg.getClass(), writer);
            writer.flush();

            reader.beginArray();
            msg = gson.fromJson(reader, Message.class);

            System.out.println(msg);

            reader.endArray();
            writer.endArray();
            reader.close();
            writer.close();

            //try{          
                //gson.toJson(msg, msg.getClass(), writer);
                //writer.flush();
            //}
            //catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean connect(String ipAddress, int port) {
            Socket s = null;
            try{
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
                s = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
                gson = new Gson();
                writer = new JsonWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")));
                reader = new JsonReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")));
                //writer.beginArray();

                Message login = new Message ("CLIENT");
                login.getH().setType("LOG");
                write(login);

                return true;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are writing to the `outputstream` but trying to read from and the `inputstream` of a socket you just opened. There won't be anything there, thus EOF, end of file.

Comment: @Sotirios Okay, but how do I essentially "wait" for a response from the server? because when I write to the outputstream the server reads the message then sends a message.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? A read operation on a socket input stream will block until there is data sent. If you got an EOF, it's possible the server has closed the stream.

Comment: Haha yeah I figured out the problem, it was literally 1 letter which was not capitalized and it resulted in the message not being sent (from the server), everything is working now, thanks!

Comment: If the question is answered, please create the answer and accept it.